# Changing Tag of Collided Object Through Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags, collision

Either the script is outdated, or it's not what I need, but I cannot find an answer to this.

To start off, I'm making a pinball styled game, whenever the ball hits a piece, it changes color, but I have multiple colored balls, and I want to lock the color in place as to not have the other balls change them (to make the game a little bit easier). I've provided a script, which may be a little too complex for a simple solution. The problem area is at the bottom with void FixedUpdate.

(I just wanna change a tag ): )

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorBlue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material mat;
    public string ballTag;
    public bool reset = false;
    public bool found = false;

    

    public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Ball" )
        {
             gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
             reset = true;
        }
    }

    public void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if(reset)
        {
            GameObject.FindWithTag("Ball");
        }   found = true;
        
        if(found)
        {
            GameObject.FindWithTag("Ball").tag = "Untagged";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for the GameObject with the *"Ball"* Tag which you probably have multiple off in your scene. You can rather just change the tag directly when the collision happens.

Because in the OnCollisionEnter Function you have a reference to the gameObject already, you can just use that to change the tag with `collisionInfo.gameObject.tag = "Untagged"`.

```cs
public void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {
    if (collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("Ball") && gameObject.CompareTag("Ball")) {
         // Get Mesh Renderer of the Colided Ball Component.
         var meshRenderer = collsionInfo.gameObject
             .GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

         // Change Color of collided ball to be the same as the ball it collided with.
         meshRenderer.material.color = gameObject
            .GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;

         // Set Tag to "Untagged" to make sure ball won't change color anymore
         colliderInfo.gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
    }
}
```

You could also add additional Code to change the color depending on the current Color of the gameObject. Additionaly I would advise you to use `CompareTag()`, which checks if the tag even exists in your scene.

If you want to get the collided gameObject you can do that with `collisionInfo.gameObject.tag`

Comment: Note that your comments inside the `switch` do not match with the behavior ;) currently nothing is changed ^^

Comment: True I'll edit the comments thx for the remark.

Comment: I think you would rather want to change the new color .. as said currently you basically do `if(currentColor == blue){ currentColor = blue; }` ;)

Comment: So, I think you guys didn't understand which thing is changing color, which is entirely my fault, so whoopsie daisy. To fix that, the thing that is changing color is the game object the ball is colliding with, not the ball itself. To make this more clear, I'm trying to make it where the ball collides with the game object, the game object changes color (which I've already managed), but I want to lock that color into place when the right colored ball hits the right piece, and I've came to the conclusion that it would be easier to change (or deactivate) the tag on the Board Piece...

Comment: ...as tags are the way I've allowed the ball to change the color of the Board Piece after collision. Moral of the story, ball hits game piece, game piece changes color, and then game piece tag changes to tag that stops collision color change from ball.

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabee Adjusted the code hope it does what you want now.

Comment: @MathewHD Yep, that done it. Appreciate the help. Much love man, have a good day

Comment: @ProgrammerWannabee If it solved your problem I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the solution so others won't attempt o answer a question that has been solved already.